# $watch doesn't work when listened to an object

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have a variable in my controller's scope and its value should be watched in a directive used on the view, something like that:

```
<grid options="gridOptions" />    // view's markup

# --- controller ---

# not important, just to show that columns loaded lazily    
schemaService.getColumns().then (cols)-> $scope.columns = cols  

$scope.gridOptions = 
  columns: $scope.columns                 # here, this wouldn't work
  # but, if done like this:
  columns: -> return $scope.columns       # note: it's a function 


# --- and inside the 'grid' directive ---

cols = -> 
  return scope.options.columns           # again this wouldn't work
  return scope.options.columns()         # but if it's done like a function - does

scope.$watch cols, (newVal, oldVal)->
    console.log "columns changed"
,true
```

So as you can see when I make the value of `gridOptions.columns` a function - it works, if I make it an object - $watch fails to see any changes,

And I don't want it as a function, I want to access it as an object, I even tried to make `gridOptions.columns` return self executable - still didn't work

I'm curious why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope.gridOptions.columns` is bound to a primitive. In order for it to behave as you desire, you'll need to modify your controller so that columns are passed by reference:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {}

schemaService.getColumns().then (cols) -> 
  $scope.gridOptions.columns = cols
```

The `$watch` in your directive will now react to changes as expected.